# What is the time complexity of Dijkstra's alogrithm using an adjacency list and priority queue?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have code likes this:

```
enqueue source vertex
while(queue is not empty){
    dequeue min vertex
    add to shortest path set
    iterate over vertex edges
        if not in shortest path set and new distance smaller enqueue 
}
```

What is the time complexity if the while loop runs for all edges in the graph instead of only running V times, for all vertices in the graph? Is it still O(ELogV) since it's O(E+E)*O(LogV)?

Comment: Can you elaborate by what you mean by "the while loop runs for all edges in the graph?" Is this more of a theoretical argument of the form "what's the time complexity of the equivalent loop?," or is there some tweak to the algorithm you're looking at making?

Comment: Well every edge is added to the queue and the while loop runs while it's not empty, so it would run E times.

Comment: How would the inner loop work? Would you iterate over the edges touching either endpoint of the current edge?

Comment: Yes, so I'd remove the smallest edge from the queue (the edge has the source and from vertex) and then I'd grab all the edges from the source vertex and enqueue them if they haven't been added to the shortest path yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is pretty much how you implement Dijkstra's algorithm when your priority queue doesn't support a DECREASE_KEY operation.  The priority queue contains (cost,vertex) records, and whenever you find a vertex cost that is lower than the previous one, you just insert a new record.

The complexity becomes O(E log E), which is no bigger than O(E log V).

This is the same complexity that Dijkstra's algorithm has when you use a binary heap that *does* support the DECREASE_KEY operation, because DECREASE_KEY takes O(log V) time.  To get down to O(E + V log V), you need to use a Fibonacci heap that can do DECREASE_KEY in constant time.