# Dijkstra's Algorithm Modified - Iterating on Edges?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have been considering a modification to the Dijkstra algorithm that would negate the need for a relaxation step. Can I get people's opinions or a reason why this would not work? My implementation centers around a priority queue of edges rather than nodes. Here is a description of my implementation:

We have a directed `Graph` class with `Node`, and `Edge` subclasses.
`Edges` have a "**weight**", a "**start**" node, and an "**end**" node.
`Nodes` have a "**dist**" value (updated with the optimal distance to reach them),
as well as a "**bestPath**" value (updated with the optimal path to reach them),
and finally an "**edges**" list.

```
Dikstra (Node origin, Node goal):
    Set settledNodes = {}
    origin.dist = 0
    settledNodes.add(origin)

    Comparator<Edge, Edge> comparator = (edge1, edge2) -> 
        compareDoubles(edge1.weight + edge1.start.dist, edge2.weight + edge2.start.dist)

    PriorityQueue<Edge> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(comparator)
    queue.addAll(origin.edges)

    while (!queue.Empty || settledNodes.size < Graph.size):
        currEdge = queue.pop()

        if (!settledNodes.contains(currEdge.end)):
            currEdge.end.bestPath = currEdge

            if (currEdge.end == goal):
               return

            currEdge.end.dist = currEdge.weight + currEdge.start.dist
            queue.add(currEdge.end.edges)
            settledNodes.add(currEdge.end)
```

Once the algorithm finishes, each node will have its "bestPath" field populated, containing the optimal edge to follow to reach that node. These edges can be back-traced in order to recreate the entire path.

I realize that my pseudocode is an unholy amalgamation of python and java - Sorry for that.

The approach here centers around iterating over a priority-queue of edges rather than a list/priority queue of nodes. What do people think? As far as I can tell it is still optimal,  and it seems to me like this algorithm is better in some ways. For instance, it does not necessarily iterate over all the edges of a node it encounters (unlike Dijkstra). It ignores long edges by throwing them to the bottom of the priority queue, and it may find an optimal route without ever processing such nodes, thus saving a few (or many!) iterations.

I am pretty excited about this algorithm, but I can't find anything like this anywhere online, which makes me think there is some deep flaw that I am overlooking. I would love to hear feedback from people.

Comment: Since your queue is initially empty, how would ```queue.pop()``` work? Or else, what values would you use to initialise queue?

Comment: Your pseudocode seems to have a lot of mistakes in it, so I'm not entirely sure, but I think what you intend is essentially the common way of implementing Dijkstra's algorithm without a decrease_key operation.  There are some answers here about that like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838314/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-dijkstras-alogrithm-using-an-adjacency-list-and/63839862#63839862 and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004917/prims-algorithm-how-to-get-index-of-key-on-which-decrease-key-operation-is-to/48017333#48017333

Comment: Sorry about that, I initialize the queue with all the edges of the origin node.

Answer (score 0):

You're suggesting running Dijkstra's on the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph). I believe this would work; however note that the asymptotic running time of Dijkstra's is O((|E| + |V|) log|V|).  By using the line graph, you're essentially swapping E and V there, making the running time worse.

Comment: It seems to me that the complexity would be O(|E| + |V|) since we will iterate through all nodes and edges at worst, although inserting edges into to the priority queue would be O(log|V|) and in the worst case we will have to do that |V| times, which means our time complexity is O(|E| + |V| + |V|log|V|) = O(|E|+|V|log|V|) which would be the same as Dijkstra's, Do you see any fault with that?

Comment: Additionally, we have been discussing big-O, the "worst case" complexity , but it seem like this algorithm, on average, will do better that Dijkstra's since Dijkstra's must iterate over every edge of each node it encounters, whereas mine will end up ignoring many edges in most practical scenarios

Comment: I would like to revise my initial comment, I think the running time would be O(|V| +log|V|) since the running time is not dependent at all on |E|